# unix regex for numeric only (period allowed)

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to clean my tsv file with awk by checking whether the column is numeric. I have tried several regex to match, but none of which works exactly as I want:

`12` -> yes

`12.01` -> yes

`12m13d` -> no

`strange` -> no

`"strange"` -> no

`strange7` -> no

I tried:

```
head  -1 file.tsv | awk -F"\t" '{
    if($6 ~ /^\d+$/)
        print;
    else;

}'
```

this return `false` for `5.6`;

I also tried:

```
head  -1 file.tsv | awk -F"\t" '{
    if(7a ~ /^-*[0-9,\.]+$/)
        printf "yes"
    else printf "no"

}'
```

but this return `true` for "7a" (I wished it returns `false`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a character class in your regex:

```
^[\d.]+$
```

Although this will pass all your examples, if you want to be more strict, use this:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

Which limits the number of periods to one.

Comment: Your second regex wouldn't match `.5`, which is a valid number, and will match `5.`, wchich is not.

Comment: +1 It won't match `5.` - it requires a number after the decimal point (if it is present).

Comment: @OGHaza not any more :) I changed the `+` to a `*` so `5.` will match. Actually I deliberately required digits after the point because I consider `5.` to be malformed, however I accept that it should match

Comment: @Bohemian I too consider `5.` malformed - I was responding to frizozoid claiming that your regex would match the malformed `5.`! Change it back!! ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you Bohemian's 2nd regex is about perfect (it's what I use for decimal number matching). On the off chance that you do want to match `.5` as well as all your examples you should use:

```
^\d*\.?\d+$
```

[Working on RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5Cd%2a%28%5C.%29?%5Cd%2b%24&input=12%0A%0A12.01%0A%0A5.%0A%0A.6%0A%0A12m13d%0A%0Astrange%0A%0A%22strange%22%0A%0Astrange7)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered just doing arithmetic on it to see if it behaves like a number, e.g. adding 0 then comparing to see if the result is equal to the original:

```
$ cat file
12 -> yes
12.01 -> yes
12m13d -> no
strange -> no
"strange" -> no
strange7 -> no

$ awk '{print $0 " => " ($1==$1+0 ? "yes" : "no")}' file
12 -> yes => yes
12.01 -> yes => yes
12m13d -> no => no
strange -> no => no
"strange" -> no => no
strange7 -> no => no
```

Comment: thanks, this is an interesting approach, but then, I will still have to know whether the result is number.

Comment: the script TELLS you if its a number or not. Not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: sorry Ed, my mistake, this seems to be a more elegant approach.